# Return a valid BusinessCard Model based on a json file using Flutter TDD

Tags: flutter, dart, automated-tests, tdd, clean-architecture

I'm trying to learn flutter TDD and I would like to make a code that should return a valid BusinessCardModel from json file that contains information about business card(s).

but when I try to run this test:

```
    import 'dart:convert';
    
    import 'package:cardatyapp/core/data/models/businessCard_model.dart';
    import 'package:cardatyapp/core/domain/entities/businessCard.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
    
    import '../../../fixtures/fixtures_reader.dart';
    
    void main() {
      final tbusinessCardModel = BusinessCardModel(
        id: '01',
        jobTitle: 'fullstack developer',
        jobDetails: 'creating fontend, backend & mobile applications',
        organization: 'freelance',
      );
    
      test('sould be a subclass of the Card entity', () {
        //assert
        expect(tbusinessCardModel, isA<BusinessCard>());
      });
    
      test(
          'should return a valid BusinessCardModel when json file contains BusinessCard',
          () async {
        //arrange
        final Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(readFixture('card.json'));
        //act
        final result = BusinessCardModel.fromJson(jsonMap);
        //assert
    
        expect(result, tbusinessCardModel);
      });
    }
```

I've got this error!
which i couldn't understand?

```
    ERROR: Expected: BusinessCardModel:<BusinessCardModel>
      Actual: BusinessCardModel:<BusinessCardModel>
```

Here are code snippets:

```
card.json file:

    {
        "uuid": "recqPz5M7tQTYesc3",
            "fav_by_user": [
                "reclZ8MXHwYKSXgNz"
            ],
            "created_by_user": [
                "recQ0XTSbKoezQCmQ"
            ],
            "job_title": "Account Executive",
            "id_card": "1",
            "organization": "Buzzshare",
            "job_details": "In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam faucibus cursus urna. Ut tellus.\n\nNulla ut erat id mauris vulputate elementum. Nullam varius. Nulla facilisi.",
        "createdTime": "2020-10-02T08:41:13.000Z"
    }
```

Business card entity:

```
    import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
    import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
    
    class BusinessCard extends Equatable {
      final String id;
      final String jobTitle;
      final String jobDetails;
      final String organization;
    
      BusinessCard({
        this.id,
        @required this.jobTitle,
        @required this.jobDetails,
        @required this.organization,
      });
    
      @override
      List<Object> get props => [
            id,
            jobTitle,
            jobDetails,
            organization,
          ];
    }
```

Business card Model (based on the precedent entity) :

```
    import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
    
    import '../../domain/entities/businessCard.dart';
    
    class BusinessCardModel extends BusinessCard {
      BusinessCardModel({
        String id,
        @required String jobTitle,
        @required String jobDetails,
        @required String organization,
      }) : super(
              id: id,
              jobTitle: jobTitle,
              jobDetails: jobDetails,
              organization: organization,
            );
      factory BusinessCardModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap) {
        return BusinessCardModel(
          id: jsonMap['id_card'],
          jobTitle: jsonMap['jobTitle'],
          jobDetails: jsonMap['jobDetails'],
          organization: jsonMap['organization'],
        );
      }
    }
```

To read the json file I'm using a fixtures reader:

```
    import 'dart:io';
    
    String readFixture(String fileName) =>
        File('test/fixtures/$fileName').readAsStringSync();
```

Please help me to understand & solve that error!

Answer (score 1):

Your `BusinessCardModel` is extending `BusinessCard` which extends `Equatable` with all members as props. As a result when you're comparing two different instance of model with different values for members, you will get false which you're doing now! The model you're expecting's `id` is `'01'` and the model you're gonna get running `BusinessCardModel.fromJson(jsonMap)` has `'1'` as `id`. You should change your `tbusinessCardModel` to match the fixture you have defined.